# Refactor python code: dynamic unpacking of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am given a frequency range `start`,`end` and an integer `n:1<=n<=5`. The task is to print all 5 linear-spaced mid points in a certain format (for other tools downstream to process it further .. this part is not imp here)
In case `n` is lesser than 5 the last frequency variables should be defaulted to `0` in the print. I have a working code given below.. I wanted to get more "pythonic" refactoring. Parts of the snippet that I particularly dislike:

1. No inherent support for dynamic unpacking of list into lesser no of variables. I have used a solution from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/144396/186398) - which is over 2 yrs old so looking for a fresh perspective
2. I don't like having to convert np array to list .. Can np be bye-passed altogether .. is there a standard library range/linspace  equivalent?

Code snippet:-

```
import sys
import numpy as np

max = 5
n=int(sys.argv[1])
if n>max:
  print("No of frequency larger than "+ str(max) + " ..resetting")
  n=max

if n<1:
  print("No of frequency less than 1 resetting to 1")
  n=1

fr1=0
fr2=0
fr3=0
fr4=0
fr5=0

start = 5060000
end   = 6165000
range = end-start
inc   = range/(n+1)

ret_list = np.arange(start+inc,end,inc).tolist()[:n]
ret_list = ret_list + [0]*(max-n)
fr1,fr2,fr3,fr4,fr5 = ret_list

print(".fr1.",fr1, sep = '')
print(".fr2.",fr2, sep = '')
print(".fr3.",fr3, sep = '')
print(".fr4.",fr4, sep = '')
print(".fr5.",fr5, sep = '')
```

Comment: Unpacking is a basic Python syntax process.  Py3 extended the syntax from Py2.  Py3.5 generalizations: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448

Comment: Python `range` only works with integer steps. But you could easily write a list comprehension that.

Comment: If you are setting all `fr#` in the unpacking, why set them to `0` earlier?

Comment: Why use unpacking?  Why not just iterate on `enumerate(ret_list)`?  `print(".fr{}.{}".format(i,x))` for each line.

Comment: `unpacking` makes sense when you have a known number of distinct values with special meanings.  It shouldn't be used as alternative to list iteration.  Variables with names like '$0','$1','$2' belong in crude shell languages, not Python.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thanks for your response! The size of `ret_list` is dependent on `n`.. I will have no way to set the last few frequencies (if n<5) to 0..

Comment: I wouldn't try to do anything fancy.  There's nothing wrong with doing some padding `if n<5:`  It's not going to run any slower.  And if it looks ugly, just hide it in a function.